# Running a function after a specific value on timer

Tags: vb.net, timer

I would like to run a specific function when the timer reach 50 a message box will show and then the specific functions run and then resets it back to 0. Could you help review and add codes that may help me with it?

Note: label1.text is where the timer shows

Appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance

```
            MessageBox.Show("Please wait were updating the data table..")
            Timer1.Stop()


            Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT PT_N_Std_Tuning, PT_TimeIn, PT_TimeOut, Variant FROM tbl_V9_Datalog WHERE Variant = '5' AND dateadd(hour, -1, dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,0,getdate()),0)) <= [PT_TimeIn]
            and PT_TimeIn < dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,0,getdate()),0) ORDER BY PT_TimeIn ASC"


            Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim command As New SqlCommand
            command.CommandText = sqlquery
            command.Connection = conn1
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            'command.Parameters.Add("@variantno", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbox_variant.Text

            reader = command.ExecuteReader


            Dim DataTableName As String = textbox1.text
            Dim dValue As Double
            Dim ID1 As String = ""
            Dim ID2 As String = ""
            Dim ID3 As String = ""
            Dim ID4 As String = ""
            Dim ID5 As String = ""
            Dim ID6 As String = ""
            Dim ID7 As String = ""
            Dim ID8 As String = ""
            Dim ID9 As String = ""
            Dim ID10 As String = ""
            Dim ID11 As String = ""
            Dim ID12 As String = ""
            Dim Note1 As String = ""
            Dim Note2 As String = ""
            Dim sDate As String = ""
            Dim sTime As String = ""
            Dim wd As Int32 = S2K_SetDataTableVariableValue(DataTableName, dValue, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5, ID6, ID7, ID8, ID9, ID10, ID11, ID12, Note1, Note2, sDate, sTime)
            Try

                If reader.HasRows Then
                    While reader.Read()
                        dValue = (Val(reader.Item("PT_N_Std_Tuning").ToString))
                        DataTableName = TextBox1.Text
                        ID1 = reader.Item("PT_TimeIn").ToString
                        ID2 = ""
                        ID3 = ""
                        ID4 = ""
                        ID5 = ""
                        ID6 = ""
                        ID7 = ""
                        ID8 = ""
                        ID9 = ""
                        ID10 = ""
                        ID11 = ""
                        ID12 = ""
                        Note1 = "" 'reader.Item("AttemptNo").ToString
                        Note2 = ""
                        Dim sDate1 = reader.GetOrdinal("PT_TimeOut")
                        sDate = reader.GetDateTime(sDate1).ToShortDateString
                        Dim sTime1 = reader.GetOrdinal("PT_TimeOut")
                        sTime = reader.GetDateTime(sTime1).ToLongTimeString
                        wd = S2K_SetDataTableVariableValue(DataTableName, dValue, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5, ID6, ID7, ID8, ID9, ID10, ID11, ID12, Note1, Note2, sDate, sTime)
                    End While


                    MessageBox.Show("Data has been updated")
                End If 
End If
```

No messagebox shown the the label reach 50 it just continously ticks

Comment: Can you post the full code showing the timer's tick event.

Comment: Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
   End Sub

Comment: Which event contains the code on your question?

Comment: Where did you enable the Timer?

Comment: What is the interval of the Timer set to?